# How do I make a material ui dropzone area not allow duplicates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-dropzone

I'm using https://yuvaleros.github.io/material-ui-dropzone/ and I'm trying to make it so that it doesn't allow uploading duplicates of previously uploaded files.

I've tried on `onchange` function that removes the file from the `<input type="file">` if there's already a file with that name that is embedded into `<DropzoneArea>` but I don't know how to remove this graphic:

[image]

I've also looked at the documentation of the Material UI Dropzone, without any luck

Comment: I had the same problem. Just trying to figure out what I did to solve.

Comment: Do you mean the exact file twice or just the same filename in different directories?

Comment: @Mordechai The exact file, i've updated my question to make it clearer

Comment: I am a contributor for `Material-ui-dropzone` If you raise an issue detailing what you need perhaps we can discuss and  schedule it for development. One possibility would be that we provide a way to `reject` the file from within the `onChange` method,

Comment: @Max Carroll Sure: https://github.com/Yuvaleros/material-ui-dropzone/issues/230

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`DropzoneAreaBase`](https://yuvaleros.github.io/material-ui-dropzone/#dropzoneareabase) which allows you to fine tune the component. You can control the files list via passing the files in the `fileObjects` array and updating in the `onAdd`/`onDelete` using your logic.

[image: Edit immutable-architecture-vq8hb]

Note, you can play around with the snackbar to not show anything when an existing file was added, I'll leave this up to you.

Comment: I tried this, and I couldn't get it to work. Could you post a code snippet where you got this to work? Thanks!

Comment: You could use something like https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @SheshankS. Done

Comment: Btw comparing the data string might not be the best solution for large files. You might rather use a combination of filename and size to assume the same file.

Comment: Just saying currently when you do npm install it goes to version 2.5.0 but in your sandbox, it's version 3. It's weird.
Attempted import error: 'DropzoneAreaBase' is not exported from 'material-ui-dropzone'.
and i got that error after doing `npm install material-ui-dropzone@3.3.1`
I'm abe to use Dropzone without the Base